# How can I get the string value of a checked item from a CheckedListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox, datarowview

I've got this code to try to extract the display value from a CheckedListBox:

```
CheckedListBox.CheckedItemCollection selectedUnits = checkedListBoxUnits.CheckedItems;
_selectedUnit = selectedUnits[0].ToString();
```

...but it doesn't work - the value of "_selectedUnit", instead of being "*platypus*" as it should be, is "*System.Data.DataRowView*".

How can I coax the string value out of this complex object?

### UPDATE

I'm not sure just what user2946329 wants to see bzg. my CheckedListBox, but here is how it is populated:

```
private void PopulateUnits()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.CPSConnStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ReportRunnerConstsAndUtils.SelectUnitsQuery, con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).DataSource = dt;
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).DisplayMember = "Unit";
                ((ListBox)checkedListBoxUnits).ValueMember = "Unit";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if there is anything missing that would help you.

Comment: I believe you want to access the Item within selectedUnits[0] and call ToString() on that, not the container itself

Comment: Take a look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @wentimo: Okay, but how do I do that ("access the item within the selectedUnits[0]"? The only thing available after a "." appended to that is ToString() - there is no "DisplayValue" or such.

Comment: @ProgrammerV5: I don't see anything at that link that helps me; the best I could derive from there was "object itemChecked = selectedUnits[0].ToString();" and that also is "System.Data.DataRow.View"

Comment: @B.ClayShannon...I think it will be better to rollback to previous version of your post for more readability. I thought showing `CheckedListBox` would help that moment!

Comment: @user2946329: Leaving it as-is gives answers to people in both situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
DataRowView dr = checkedListBoxUnits.CheckedItems[0] as DataRowView;
string Name = dr["Unit"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the string you get (`"System.Data.DataRowView"`), you use the `CheckListBox` with datasource attached. If that's the case, in `CheckedItems` you really get `DataRowViews`.. hence the string, since its ToString() returns class name. You will need to access the data from the `DataRowView`, by column name or index.

Answer (score 1):

```
_selectedUnit = ((DataRowView)selectedUnits[0])["Name"].ToString();
```

the key is to typecast the item before accessing it...

Answer (score 0):

Combining user2946329's answer with Resharper's contribution, the code I ended up using is:

```
String _selectedUnit;
. . .
DataRowView dr = checkedListBoxUnits.CheckedItems[0] as DataRowView;
if (dr != null) _selectedUnit = dr["Unit"].ToString();
```

(Resharper complained about a possible null reference issue, and so added the "if (dr != null)" jazz to the last line.

Comment: You could also get OutOfRange exception if there are none items checked in the list, since you directly access item at index 0 without any check whether or not there is such item.

Comment: Yes, theoretically it's not possible, because the "Go" button is disabled until a unit has been selected (among other things), but I know it's better to be defensive than offensive when it comes to programming.