# Why "SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWVIEW " is displayed instead of column name?

Tags: c#

I have two `ListBoxes` and one `ComboBox` in my forms application. I want to add the current selected item from all 3 of them (two `ListBoxes` and one `ComboBox`)to a new `TextBox`. However, I'm getting the column name as:

> SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWVIEW

Here's the code I'm using:

```
private void listBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cmdstr = @"select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "'";
    string conStr = @"Data Source=INPDDBA027\NGEP;Initial Catalog=Dev_Server;Integrated Security=True";
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdstr, conStr);
    sda.Fill(dt);
    //listBox2.DataSource = dt;
    //listBox2.DisplayMember = "Column_Name";
    textBox2.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
    textBox2.Text = (listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + " " + listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() + " FROM " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588605/copy-items-from-listbox-to-checkedlistbox

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34422684/how-can-i-get-the-string-value-of-a-checked-item-from-a-checkedlistbox/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [GetItemText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cbtzx5b1.aspx) method:

```
listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

For `combobox` use

```
this.ComboBox.GetItemText(this.ComboBox.SelectedItem);
```

Comment: No problem @AnkushSoni, glad it did :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the both:

**listBox1.DataValueField="fieldValue"** and  **listBox1.DataTextField="textValue"**

**listBox2.DataValueField="fieldValue"** and **listBox2.DataTextField="textValue"**

Answer (score 0):

While you can manipulate

```
listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
```

using a `cast` like

```
((DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem)["Enter column name here"].ToString();
```

to retrieve the data out of the `SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWVIEW` you've added to the listbox, a better option might be to look into how you're populating your listbox in the first place so it just contains the strings you need and not a collection of `SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWVIEW`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the selected item as

```
string variable =  listBox1.SelectedValue;
```

and the Text of the selected item as

```
string variable = listBox1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Hope That helps !!!